# can we extract multiple data from a single query using string functions in mysql?

Tags: mysql, substring

I am wonder if i can extract multiple data with a single query using string operations.?

Here is what i am looking for
My query returns me

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|               geodata                   |
+-----------------------------------------+
| {"lat"=>"28.644348", "lon"=>"77.219682" |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

Can i extract `lat` value and `lon` value through any string query?

i tried and succeed up to extracting a single value.

can anyone suggest me how to do this?

of-course i can do this after pulling this data to my rails app but i am thinking to pull this data directly from the query.

Comment: show us what you tried and we can go from there.

Comment: select replace(substring_index('{"lat"=>"28.644348", "lon"=>"77.219682" ','"',-2),'"','');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it could be done assuming that the pattern you shown is same

```
mysql> select replace(substring_index(substring_index('{"lat"=>"28.644348", "lon"=>"77.219682"','"lat"=>',-1),',',1),'"','') as lat;
+-----------+
| lat       |
+-----------+
| 28.644348 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select replace(substring_index(substring_index('{"lat"=>"28.644348", "lon"=>"77.219682"','"lon"=>',-1),',',1),'"','') as lon;
+-----------+
| lon       |
+-----------+
| 77.219682 |
+-----------+
```

So finally you can combine both of them into a single select

```
select 
replace(substring_index(substring_index(geodata,'"lat"=>',-1),',',1),'"','') as lat,
replace(substring_index(substring_index(geodata,'"lon"=>',-1),',',1),'"','') as lon
from your_table
```